# VBA Object/Application defined error

Tags: vba, if-statement, for-loop

Here is some code that gives me a Object defined or Application defined error.  Can you guys please help?  Thanks in advance

The error comes on the check for matching cell line.

```
Sub check()

Dim y, x, xb As Integer

'vertical step

For y = 12 To 65

    'check if cell have value
      If Not IsEmpty(Sheet2.Cells(y, 4)) Then

        'horizontal step
          For x = 70 To 600
              xb = x + 1
            'checks for matching cell value
              If Sheet2.Cells(6, x).Value = Sheet2.Cells(y, 4).Value Then

                'sees if the next col over after match is empty
                   If Not IsEmpty(Sheet2.Cells(y, xb)) Then

                    'if not then highlight cell in col d
                     Sheet2.Cells(y, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 3


                    End If

               End If

          Next x

      End If

    Next y

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `Sheet2`. You can do that by declaring it at the top of your code with:

```
Dim Sheet2 As Worksheet
Set Sheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
```

From there you can use `With Sheet2` to use it like so:

```
Sub check()

Dim y, x, xb As Integer
Dim Sheet2 As Worksheet

Set Sheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

'vertical step

With Sheet2

    For y = 12 To 65

        'check if cell have value
          If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(y, 4)) Then

            'horizontal step
              For x = 70 To 600

                  xb = x + 1

                'checks for matching cell value
                  If .Cells(6, x).Value = .Cells(y, 4).Value Then

                    'sees if the next col over after match is empty
                       If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(y, xb)) Then

                        'if not then highlight cell in col d
                         .Cells(y, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 3

                        End If

                   End If

              Next x

        End If

    Next y

End With

End Sub
```